# Prevent ListView selection rectangle from crossing columns header

Tags: c, listview, winapi

The selection rectangle in my ListView is crossing the columns header:

[image]

I have tried to create a ListView in .NET and the selection rectangle in it did not cross the columns header:

[image]

So how can I prevent this behavior in Windows API?

This is the code I used to create the ListView:

```
HWND hListView = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, "", WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 320, 200, hWnd, 0, hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: Hmm, the .NET behavior is a bug, not a feature.  Use Spy++ to compare the header control style flags.

Comment: `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` does the same thing, but I don't know why. `DWORD f = LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER; ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx(ListView, f, f);`

Comment: Does `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` use a real header control?

Comment: @andlabs What do you mean by "a real header control"? When I set the `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` extended style, two things happened: 1) The selection rectangle did not cross the columns header. 2) The selection rectangle color has changed to blue (the same as in Windows Explorer).

Comment: Oh, then disregard my comment. I thought `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` exposed the behavior you're trying to avoid.